# A global inequality of perturbation analysis of convex optimization

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, perturbation-theory

My questions are originated from the book [Convex Optimization written by Stephen P. Boyd](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Convex_Optimization/IUZdAAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0), where a proof of a global inequality of perturbation analysis puzzles me. And here are my questions:

- In the proof of the inequality $5.57$, how can the first inequality hold when we might have two different domains for unperturbed and perturbed problems? (I can only get the inequality for all feasible points of unperturbed problem, while having no ideas about the points belonging to the perturbed problem which are not feasible for the unperturbed problem)
- Is this true for a problem of a non-convex objective with a convex inequality constraint (suppose our perturbation is always greater than zero)? Or is there any weaker result for non-convex problems I can resort to?

Those two problems are:

- Unperturbed problem
  \begin{equation}
  \begin{array}
  \displaystyle \text{minimize} & f_{0}(x)\\
  \textrm{s.t.} & f_{i}(x) \leq 0, i=1,\dots, m \\
  & h_{i}(x) = 0, i=1,\dots, p\\
  \end{array}
  \end{equation}
- Perturbed problem
  \begin{equation}
  \begin{array}
  \displaystyle \text{minimize} & f_{0}(x)\\
  \textrm{s.t.} & f_{i}(x) \leq u_{i}, i=1,\dots, m \\
  & h_{i}(x) = v_{i}, i=1,\dots, p\\
  \end{array}
  \end{equation}

Below is the image of the captured content of the inequality and its proof provided by the author.

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

I can answer your question 1. In this context we assume strong duality holds, and KKT conditions hold. In particular, we have the primal optimal point $x^*$ together with $(\lambda^*, \nu^*)$ satisfy $$
\nabla f(x^*)+\sum_{i=1}^m \lambda_i^* \nabla f_i(x^*) +\sum_{i=1}^p \nu_i^*\nabla h_i(x^*)=0 $$
Note that the function on the RHS of the first inquality is convex in $x$ and its derivative vanishes at $x^*$, so $x^*$ is the global minimizer, i.e. $g(\lambda^*,\nu^*)=\min_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n} f(x)+\sum_{i=1}^m \lambda_i^* f_i(x) +\sum_{i=1}^p \nu_i^*h_i(x)$. Hence the first inequality is true for every $x\in \cap \textbf{ dom} f_i$, not only for the feasible points of unperturbed problem.

Comment: I believe the contradiction is that by definition, $g(\lambda^{\star}, \nu^{\star})$ only accounts for the domain of the unperturbed problem but not necessarily for the perturbed problem because no constraint is applied to both $\mu$ and $v$. Unless the constraints are tightened, it is not conclusive for the first inequality.

Comment: I've edited my answer to be more detailed. I agreed with your point that for any dual variable $(\lambda,\nu)$, by definition, it only accounts for the feasible primal sets on which it finds a minimizer. However, for the optimal dual variable, we have an extra "condition", KKT condition, which ensures that the dual function reaches global minumum at $x^*$ even though the $x^*$ is chosen from the primal feasible set.

Comment: It is nothing wrong with unperturbed problem, for which $x^{\star}$ is the global minimum as such $x^{\star} = \inf\{f_{0}(x) | f_{i}(x) \leq 0, h_{i}(x) = 0\}$. But is is not valid for perturbed problem $\inf\{f_{0}(x) | f_{i}(x) \leq \mu_{i}, h_{i}(x) = v_{i}\}$. However, a tradeoff would be considering $x \in \textbf{dom}_{\text{unperturbed}}\cap \textbf{dom}_{\text{perturbed}}$.